# How do I use a VLookup as range parameter in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an IF statement working fine, but I need to use a VLookup as a range, as the cell that is the subject of the IF could be in a different row, but never a different column.

I'm brand new to VBA (but not to excel), so the VLookup was an instinctive move, but I'm not tied to it if I can achieve the same thing another way. I've been trying to find solutions online, but don't seem to actually answer this query.

The below is the original code with a static range.

```
Sub FINDTOTAL()

Dim Amount As String
Amount = "Subtotal"

thetotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Amount, Sheet1.Range("G:H"), 2, False)

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub CalculateSubtotal()

If Range("H25") > 10000 Then
    Sheets("Billing").Select
Else
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H25").Copy
    MsgBox "Subtotal has been copied and can be pasted into the quote"

End If
End Sub
```

The VLookup works, and the IF statement works, I just can't get them to work together. I need the subtotal to be assessed for the IF statement regardless of where it is in the column (in probability, it could be anywhere between rows 3 - 50).

Comment: You can test the result of the vlookup without knowing what cell it's in, I'm not sure you need to know the range. If you really need to know the range, you could use `Find` to find `Subtotal` in Column G, and then use `Offset` to refer to the cell in Column H.

Comment: Thanks for this - do you have an example of how to use this in the context of an IF statement? I went looking but can't seem to find much about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
Sub FindTotal()

    Dim Total As Variant
    Total = Application.VLookup("Subtotal", Sheet1.Range("G:H"), 2, False)

    If Not IsError(Total) Then
        If IsNumeric(Total) Then
            If Total > 10000 Then
                ' Do one thing
            Else
                ' Do another thing
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

If you want to write the total to another cell elsewhere, you don't need to copy, just a direct value transfer.

---

Demonstrating a `Find`/`Offset` approach:

```
Sub FindTotal()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Columns("G").Cells.Find(What:="Subtotal")

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Dim totalRng As Range
        Set totalRng = rng.Offset(, 1)

        If IsNumeric(totalRng.Value) Then
            If totalRng.Value > 10000 Then
                ' Do one thing
            Else
                ' Do another thing
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```